# SQL - My query is not working

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

1. Art (oid,subject,type)
2. Artist (aid, name)
3. Artistic (oart (as a foreign key to oid), author (as a foreign key to aid))

So, i have to find the subjects and the number of artists for every type of art with the minimum number of artists.

I wrote the following but apparently it's not working. Can anybody help me?

```
SELECT o.subject, COUNT(au.autor)  count
FROM Artistic au, Art o
WHERE o.oid=au.autor
GROUP BY o.type
HAVING count = (SELECT MIN(count) FROM Artistic au);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not working* ? Do you get an error - if so **WHAT** error? Are you not getting the expected results ? Then please show us source data, what you expected to get, and what you're really getting. We cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to provide the information so we can help!

Comment: I'm sorry you are right i had to give more informations. I used join syntax and it's working now. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the calculated column, not the ALIAS. 
*use also proper join syntax*

```
SELECT o.subject, 
       COUNT(au.autor) count
FROM   Artistic au
       INNER JOIN Art o
          ON o.oid = au.autor
GROUP  BY o.type, o.subject
HAVING COUNT(au.autor) = (SELECT MIN(count) FROM Artistic au)
```

Comment: I have already tried this.. but it still doesn't work..

Comment: I updated the answer. You also need to include `o.subject` in the `GROUP BY` clause. If the result of the statement is not the one you expect, please give sample records and your desired result so we can work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:  "I have to find the subjects and the number of artists for every type of art with the minimum number of artists".

This type of query is a bit of a pain in MySQL.  You need to aggregate by `type` and `subject`, then choose the `subject`s that have the minimum count.  That requires additional `join` operations:

```
SELECT ts.`type`, ts.subject, ts.count
FROM (SELECT a.`type`, a.subject, COUNT(au.autor) as `count`
      FROM Artistic au join
           Art a
           on a.oid = au.autor
      GROUP BY a.`type`, a.subject
     ) ts join
     (select a.`type`, min(`count`) as mincount
      from (SELECT a.type, a.subject, COUNT(au.autor) as `count`
            FROM Artistic au join
                 Art a
                 on a.oid = au.autor
            GROUP BY a.type, a.subject
           ) ts
      group by a.`type`
     ) t
     on t.`type` = ts.`type`
ORDER BY `count` desc;
```